# Accordion menu/sub-menu offset

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: menu sample]

I have an accordion menu that currently expands and collapses all with the same container of the menu system boundaries. My question is, (see menu sample), how can I take the sub-menu of my accordion menu, i.e. the expanded bit, that currently shows "Pool & Spa Maintenance" in the attached example and have it display as a sub-menu container to the right of its parent "Pool & Spa"?

It's almost like a z-index where I want the sub-menu to overlap the parent menu container but all still be part of the same menu system.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you want an opening menu why use accordion?...

accordion is for one thing and a menu with opened sub menus is totally other..

you need somekind of jquery menu that open to the side
try looking for somekind of plugin that will do exactly that here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44


not an accordion

Comment: thanks for your input but any reason why I can't just use an accordion menu and somehow move accross to the right, a submenu? I guess my main question should have been on how this might be possible using css etc and not so concerned with actual menu selection.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to supply some of your code at least enough for us to see what is happening and how to fix it.

If your main links are `position: relative` then you should be able to have your sub nav as `position: absolute` and also tell it to sit to the `right: -100px; top: 0px;`

These coordinates might not be 100% what you need. but as I said we need to see some code first